# JTable not populating data from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jtable, swig

I am trying to populate data stored in my database into JTable. I have a `println` statement "records added to db" and it prints it out 18 times so the number of rows in the db matches the number of printed statements. However i get nothing displaying in my JTable and I don't know where the mistake is.

Code:

```
try {
        conn = SQLConnect.ConnectDb();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM CriminalRecords WHERE FName = ? and Sname = ?";

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, NameSearch.getText());
        pst.setString(2, SurnameSearch.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

            //display data from db into table hmm  
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnNumber = md.getColumnCount();
            Vector columns = new Vector(columnNumber);

            //  Get column names
            //store column names
            for(int i=1; i<=columnNumber; i++) 
            {
                columns.add(md.getColumnName(i));
            } 

            Vector data = new Vector();
            Vector row;

        //store row data
        while(rs.next())
        {
            row = new Vector(columnNumber);
            for(int i=1; i<=columnNumber; i++)
            {
                row.add(rs.getObject(i));
                System.out.println("Records added to Table");
            }
            data.add(row);

        }
        JTable table1 = new JTable(data, columns);
        this.add(table1);
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
        conn.close();
```

JTable code

```
/---- table1 ----
            table1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][] {
                    {" ", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                },
                new String[] {
                    "First Name", "Middle Name", "Surname", "Date of Birth", "Address", "Home Phone", "Business Phone", "Mobile Phone", "Resident Status", "Sex", "Race", "Incident Location", "Zone", "Premise Type", "Date Recorded", "Time Recorded", "Weapons", "Crime Offences"
                }
            ));
            table1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
            scrollPane1.setViewportView(table1);
```

Comment: how are you expecting to see the data?  do you iterate over the Vector somewhere else?

Comment: where in the above code do you see  JTable? youre adding rows to a Vector, but no JTable in sight

Comment: Oh i see ok, so i should now add vectors to Jtable, or there is easier and quicker way of doing it?

Comment: @maciejcygan Based on your last comment, I suggest you have a read through [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: ok thx i will look through it, i haven't worked with tables yet so i am new to this aspect of java.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - i have made some changes to the code now, but i still dont get the result that i want - Code in post has been updated to the current version

Comment: Ok although i have found a method to solve my problem it isn't the best but it works. So i guess the topic can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution although it's not the best but it works and that will do me for now.

```
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
//
//
//
try {
        conn = SQLConnect.ConnectDb();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM CriminalRecords WHERE FName = ? and Sname = ?";

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, NameSearch.getText());
        pst.setString(2, SurnameSearch.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        table1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

} catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DatabaseP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```